# I can't install unity-tweak-tool in Ubuntu even apt-get -f install

Tags: unity, apt, unity-tweak-tool

I tried to install unity tweak tool in my Ubuntu but it always failed. I searched around google and see all forums but no solution works. I think Ubuntu is becoming buggy, here is my terminal record:

```
    mrna@MrNA:~$ sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool 
[sudo] password for mrna: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-tweak-tool : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon but it is not going to be installed
 unity-tweak-tool : Depends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
mrna@MrNA:~$ apt-get -f install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
mrna@MrNA:~$ sudo su
root@MrNA:/home/mrna# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  hwdata libboost-filesystem1.58.0 libmirclient9 libmircommon5 libmirprotobuf3
  signon-plugin-password
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gnome-settings-daemon
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-settings-daemon
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1096 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1.149 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7.188 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 254458 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-settings-daemon_3.22.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-settings-daemon (3.22.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-settings-daemon_3.22.1-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/GConf/gsettings/gnome-settings-daemon.convert', which is also in package gnome-settings-daemon-schemas 3.18.2-0ubuntu3
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-3ubuntu6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-settings-daemon_3.22.1-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@MrNA:/home/mrna#
```

Please help me I know there are many questions in askubuntu like me but non of the solution works, thank you!

Comment: try `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: try  `sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-common`